# Casting negative integer to DATE in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, navicat

I'm having a problem working with a Navicat Database. I got a column in SQL called fechaNacimiento (Birthdate) that should be a Date type, but instead it's stored as integers (most negative integers):

```
SELECT fechaNacimiento FROM Registrados
```

And I'm getting:

```
fechaNacimiento
-1451678400
-2082829392
-1798746192
-1199221200
-1356984000
-694299600
-1483214400
-1924976592
-1830368592
-2019670992
-1678909392
239252400
1451617200
-879541200
```

I don't know how this dates where loaded, I just know that inside that negative integer there's a date, and nobody here have any clue about how to spell SQL, so I have nobodoy to ask. If I just cast it to DATETIME, I get all of them as NULL values. Any idea in how to convert this data to Date type?

Comment: Any idea what the dates represent?

Comment: What do you mean with "what they represent"? They're the birthdates of +60yo people if that's what you're asking.

Comment: They look like epoch millis to me. Fairly standard way of storing dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers like that make me think of Unix times, number of seconds since 1970.  If so, you might be able to do:

```
select dateadd(second, <column>, '1970-01-01')
```

This would put the negative values sometime before 1970 (for instance, -1678909392 is 1916-10-19).  If you have older dates, then that might be the format being used.

These might also be represented as milliseconds.  If so:

```
select dateadd(second, <column>/1000, '1970-01-01')
```

In this case, -1678909392 represents 1969-12-12.

In MySQL, you would use:

```
select '1970-01-01' + interval floor(column / 1000) second
```

Comment: Or this may be milliseconds as well `dateadd(ms,-2019670992,cast('20000101' as datetime2))`= '08.12.1999 14:58:49' Only a table creator probably knows.

Comment: Navicat didn't recognize me the function DATEADD, but I used instead DATE_ADD('1970-01-01', INTERVAL <column> SECOND) and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @Serg . . . Here is an interesting list of reference epoch starts for different computing systems:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date).  Interestingly, I don't put 2000-01-01 high on the list,   And the list leaves out 1960-01-01, which is SAS's epoch.

Comment: @Cris . . . If your database does not support `dateadd()`, then it is not SQL Server.  I am changing the tag.